# Is this error Important? Component uncontrolled to controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I actually prefer the design because it allows me to reuse the component easily with react state or redux state. But I am getting this warning. What do you suggest I do?

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: 
>       in input (created by InventoryDisplay)
>       in InventoryDisplay (created by Connect(InventoryDisplay))
>       in Connect(InventoryDisplay)
>       in PersistGate

```js
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {mapStatesToProps, mapDispatchToProps} from '../../redux/maps/maps';

class InventoryDisplay extends React.PureComponent{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        
        this.state={
            pagnation: true,
            firstPage: null,
            currentPage: null,
            lastPage:null,
            data:null,
            limit:null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        //sets the value of the inventory here
        this.props.loadInventory();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){

        console.log(this.props.CurrentInventory)
        this.setState({ 
          currentPage:this.props.CurrentInventory.current_page 
        })
        this.setState({ 
          firstPage: this.props.CurrentInventory.from 
        })
        this.setState({ 
          lastPage: this.props.CurrentInventory.last_page 
        })
        this.setState({ data: this.props.CurrentInventory.data })
        this.setState({ total: this.props.CurrentInventory.total })
        this.setState({ 
          limit: this.props.CurrentInventory.per_page 
        })
    }
 
    render(){
      return(
        <label>
          <span>Items</span>
          <input className={'text-center'} type={'text'} size={2} 
value={this.state.limit}/>
       </label>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStatesToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(InventoryDisplay);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

```
in Provider
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because, the value of your input is `this.state.limit` but you're not updating it. When the value of input is changed, the value of `state` is not changing. You have to give an `onChange` handler so that whenever the value inside your input changes, the value of the state also changes, rerendering the value inside your input. You can do something like 
`<input className={'text-center'} type={'text'} size={2} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} value={this.state.limit}/>`

and write an onChangeHandler that looks something like

```
onChangeHandler = (e) => {
 setState({limit: e.target.value})
}
```

Read more about controlled componenets [in React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)